# Sum of a big divisor and a pseudo-effective divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$.

It is well-known that the sum of an ample divisor and an effective divisor is big (in fact this can be taken to be the definition of a big divisor). I'm looking for a weakening of this.

> Is the sum of a big divisor and a pseudo-effective divisor itself a big divisor?

Recall that a divisor is called *pseudo-effective* if it lies in the closure of the cone of effective divisors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say the big divisor is $B$ and the pseudoeffective one is $F$.  Write $B = A + E$ with $A$ ample and $E$ effective (by Kodaira).  Then $B+F = A+E+F = A/2 + E + (F + A/2)$.  $F+A/2$ is effective since $F$ is psef, and so we've written $B+F$ as ample plus effective, so it's big.

Comment: This looks promising. Though why is  $F + A/2$ effective?

Comment: @DanielLoughran All classes in some ball around $A/2$ are ample, hence effective. One can look at a ball around $F$ of the same size, and find an effective class in it because $F$ is pseudoeffective. Then $F + A/2$ is that class plus an ample class.

Answer (score 7):

Theorem 2.2.26 of Lazarsfeld's [*Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2095471), 2004, is the following:

**Theorem:** The big cone is the interior of the pseudoeffective cone and the pseudoeffective cone is the closure of the big cone.

These are convex cones. So the sum of a big class and a pseudoeffective class is in the interior of the cone, i.e., once again a big class.

The proof of this theorem is pretty much along the lines of the above answer. So not an independent answer here, just offering a citation.